# Converting a linux machine to virtual machine

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, backup, virtualization

I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and Windows 8.1 on dual boot, using GRUB Loader to select between operating systems. I want to convert my Ubuntu physical machine to virtual. I've looked into VMware Converter but it needs another system running Windows for remote connection which I don't have access to at the moment. I'm planning to run a backup software like CloneZilla to create image. But can this image be restored on my virtual machine?

And if I'm deleting Linux partition what is the safest way to accomplish it? Without damaging the Windows partition or startup. (I ended up messing this up last time when I had Windows 7 and BackTrack)

Comment: IMO you are best off just doing a fresh install.

Comment: You could make an iso of your current install and transfer that to VM , with remastersys, but that's just a theory and besides , if your Ubuntu partition is large it will take a lot of time transferring. Better approach is to backup config files and personal files, install fresh vm, and send files there through shared folder with host os

Answer (score 0):

Frankly the easiest way to convert Ubuntu to a virtual machine IMHO, is to reinstall Ubuntu in the virtual machine on the host machine.  Certainly this method will be the least error prone.

You can start the process of installation, get the VM working to your satisfaction, and then place any important documents onto a USB stick to transfer to the new machine, without screwing with your current physical machine.

When all is operating correctly, you can then delete the physical machine, and reclaim the space for other purposes.

Comment: You can use Aptik to transfer all your installed programs.